# Create vector = (0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1)?

Tags: r, vector, zero, rep

How can I create the following vector?

```
vec = (0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1)
```

I already tried `rep(0:1,times=1:4)` which works with numbers other than 0 but does not here...=

Comment: `rep(rep(0:1,2),times=1:4)`

Comment: not randomly, its one 0, two 1's, three 0's, for 1's...

Comment: or `rep(rep(0:1,length.out=4),times=1:4)`

Answer (score 4):

For rep, 'times' and 'x' need to have the same length (unless the length of 'times' equals 1). Therefore, you need to make a vector 'x' with length 4 in this case.

```
> rep(rep(0:1,2),times=1:4)
 [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generic solution:

```
> increp=function(n){rep(0:(n-1), times=1:n) %% 2}
> increp(4)
 [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
> increp(3)
[1] 0 1 1 0 0 0
> increp(2)
[1] 0 1 1
> increp(6)
 [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

It generates `0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3` up to the required length and then just converts to 0/1 based on even or odd.